# Object Light Emission - only on certain surfaces

Tags: materials

noob here.
I am successfully applied light emission on a object - that object however is somewhat a merger of several objects made with CAD software and imported as STL.

long story short, I can either split that object which will be (for me) rather complicated due to the geometry of the part, or cheat (if possible) and only apply the light emission material to certain surfaces of that object.

Is there a way to do that? right now the whole object is glowing and I would like to limit the glow to certain surface of that object.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a object with multiple material. 
In the material panel, there is a small '+' icon on the right, to add a new material slot. And define the second material you want to use.

Now got to edit mode (Tab), and select the faces you want for this secondary material. Then in the material panel hit assign.

[image: Mutliple material on one object]

However, this does not the change that it will be cumbersome for you the select the correct part of your CAD.

Maybe it's will be easier for you to split your CAD data in various file (or group some pieces in one file) and then in you CAD software export various STL file. Then you'll just have to set a meterial per STL file.

Comment: thanks - it's a rather large assembly with dozens of imported STL and re-exporting the STL will be a lot of work. I'll try to edit and select the couple surfaces I need by hiding the other objects. Thanks again!

Comment: What you can try is separate the object by loose parts. In edit mode type P and separate by loose parts.